# Ruby: changing the appearances strings without changing their original values

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create spider solitaire with Ruby. I want to show only the first element in an array on screen. For example...

```
a = ["AH", "1H", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H"]
```

This array represents a pile of cards from Ace to 5 in suits of heart. 
I would like the program to print on screen...

```
a = ["AH", "CARD", "CARD", "CARD", "CARD", "CARD"]
```

But I would still want a[1] to return "1H", not "CARD". Is there a way to change the appearances of strings without changing their original values?.

Comment: You can write your own methods for displaying things, you're not forced to `puts a`.

Answer (score 3):

```
puts a.map.with_index{|e, i| i.zero? ? e : "CARD"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make two arrays: one true and unaltered representation of the deck that is only visible to the game, and a second representation that displays cards the player is allowed to see.

```
game_deck = ["AH", "1H", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H"]
display_deck = ["AH", "CARD", "CARD", "CARD", "CARD", "CARD"]
```

As the game progresses, you can reveal new cards in the `display_deck` by consulting the `game_deck`.

Answer (score 0):

A literal answer:

```
def print_mostly_cards(a)
  print "a = \"[#{a.first}\""
  (a.size-1).times { print ', "CARD"' }
  puts "]"
end

a = ["AH", "1H", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H"]
print_mostly_cards(a)
  a = "[AH", "CARD", "CARD", "CARD", "CARD", "CARD"]
```